# SQL raised to a power of error "An invalid floating point operation occurred."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this code

```
declare @termtomonths float
set @termtomonths=120/365.00 
set @termtomonths= round(@termtomonths,2,1)*12
select power(1-(1+0.11/12.00), -3.84)
```

When i run it, it return an error of

```
    Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
An invalid floating point operation occurred.
```

It try this formula in MS EXCEL and it works

```
=1-(1+0.11/12)^-3.84
```

expected result

```
  0.034432865
```

How can I possibly convert this excel formula to sql formula?

Thanks

Comment: You are getting the error in sql because base is a negative number and exponent is not an integer. `1-(1+0.11/12) = -0.009166` <-- base and `-3.84` <--- exponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression is wrong in SQL.
To get the same as you have in Excel you should do this:

```
SELECT  1 - POWER(( 1 + 0.11 / 12.00 ), -3.84);
```

This gives you: `0.0344326`
Note you have the `1 -` inside the POWER function in SQL, but not in Excel.

The error is what also causes you to get the floating point error, because your base cannot be negative.